# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined in Reactjs while mapping twice

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON structure which should have mapped function twice in a loop to access the objects in Array. After mapping I need a text box to search the list of data. But I am getting the below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

**Below is the my JSON Structure :**

```
{
  "brand": [
     {

    "title": "Brands",
    "options": [
    {
     "catgeory_name": "Sigma"
    },
    {
     "catgeory_name": "Footner"
    }
   ]
     }
  ]
}
```

**Below is the component code**

```
class TvFilter extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     searchInput: '',
   };
  }
}
onSearchInputChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({ searchInput: e.target.value })
}
elementContainsSearchString = (searchInput, element) => (searchInput ? element.catgeory_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) : false);

filterItems = (itemList) => {
        let result = [];
        const { searchInput } = this.state;
        let filterbrands = this.props.tvfilter.brand
        if (filterbrands) { 
            console.log (filterbrands);
        } else {
            return 'loading...'
        }
        if (itemList && (searchInput)) {
            result = itemList.filter((element) => this.elementContainsSearchString(searchInput, element));
        } else {
            result = itemList || [];
        }

        result = filterbrands.map((item) => (
            <dl>
                <dt><input type="search" onChange={this.onSearchInputChange} className="pull-right" placeholder="Search by Brand" /></dt>
                <dt>{item.title}</dt>
                {
                    item.options.map(catname =>
                        <dd key={catname.catgeory_name} className={catname.catgeory_name} ><a href="#">{catname.catgeory_name}</a></dd>
                    )
                }
            </dl>
        ));
        return result;
    }
```

**Render Function**

```
render() {
  let filterbrands = this.props.tvfilter.brand
  const filteredList = this.filterItems(filterbrands);
  if (filterbrands) { } else {
  return 'loading...'
  }
  return (
    <div className="">
       {filteredList}
    </div>
    );
  }
```

The error is on this function where it is not getting the data because of nested mapping.

```
elementContainsSearchString = (searchInput, element) => (searchInput ? element.catgeory_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) : false);
```

Comment: make sure you posted correct json format ? and this.props.tvfilter.brand contains that JSON ?

Comment: It is working without issues. Refer this https://codesandbox.io/s/wq30oz7y7k  Note: I have fixed the JSON issue. Refer the updated JSON.

Comment: Sorry, Missed brackets in JSON while posting the question. Just edited.

Comment: @SelvaTS It does not throw error in your sandbox but it does not filter result as well. Try to type in the box and filter. So may be something else is wrong.

Comment: @LukášGiboVaic : That is the original JSON which is there in the question, I just removed some of the objects to make it short. 
However `element.catgeory_name` is undefined, that is the problem.

Comment: @H.Husain the `catgeory_name` in the JSON is an array (options). You need to flatten the array of array before filtering the values.

Comment: @SelvaTS Do you have any sample for the above JSON format to flatten the array of arrays, I have tried `.concat` but it is not giving the desired result.

Comment: @H.Husain it seems your JSON itself not formed well. Please consider reformatting this JSON.

Comment: Currently this is the JSON which i will receive from the endpoint, difficult to modify the format, can we do something in this format only ?

Comment: @H.Husain I have fixed the JSON search issue and updated some code. Please refer this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/014vr73q0p

Answer (score 0):

```
result = itemList[0].options.filter((element) => this.elementContainsSearchString(searchInput, element));
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: While this answer will solve the question, you should add an explanation instead of simply posting code.

Comment: @Ashish Kumar : It does not resolve the issue with this, throwing the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: @H.Husain: I have updated the answer. Please try it one more time.